# Если аргумент является string, как преобразовать ее в number и наоборот. Он должен возвращать массив преобразованных значений

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

```js
function convert() {
  let a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
  if (typeof(a) === Number) {
    String(a)
  }
  return String(a).split(',')
}
console.log(convert("1", 2, 3, "4")); //результат [1, '2', '3', 4]
console.log(convert(5, 6, 23, "66")); //результат ['5, '6', '23', 66]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function convert(...args) {
  let array = []
  for (let key in args)
  {
      if(typeof args[key] === "number")
      {
          array.push(args[key].toString())
      }
      else if(typeof args[key] === "string")
      {
          array.push(parseInt(args[key]))
      }   
  }
  console.log(array)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том что в аргументе мы передаем не массив  а convert( "1", 2, 3, "4" ) а на выходе должен быть массив

Comment: Я поправил, конечно, под ваш пример, но ответ даётся на конкретный вопрос. Вопрос состоял в преобразовании, а не в остаточных параметрах.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const convert = (...str) => str.map((el) => {
  return typeof el === "string" ? +el : String(el)
});

console.log(convert("1", 2, 3, "4")); //результат [1, '2', '3', 4]
console.log(convert(5, 6, 23, "66")); //результат ['5, '6', '23', 66]
```